# How to use camera_info_manager to publish camera_info

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-info, camera-info-manager, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to calibrate my ov7251 camera using the camera_calibration package. I adapted a sample camera driver that I found which use the UV4L API so that I can try to publish images to the ROS topic /camera/image. I am also publishing to /camera/camera_info. However, what I need now is to be able to run the /camera/set_camera_info service so that I can use the calibration package.

Here is my code for publishing to /camera/image and /camera/camera_info:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dev_name = "/dev/video2";

    namedWindow( "Camera Preview", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("camera/image", 1);

    ros::Publisher pub_info = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>("camera/camera_info", 100);
    sensor_msgs::CameraInfo cam_info;

    open_device();
    init_device();
    start_capturing();

    while (nh.ok()) {
        read_frame();
        if (!prev.empty()) {
            cv::Mat image = prev;
            sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", image).toImageMsg();

            ros::Rate loop_rate(5);

            cam_info.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
            pub_info.publish(cam_info);
            pub.publish(msg);
            ros::spinOnce();
            loop_rate.sleep();
        }  
    }

   ...

   return 0;
}
```

When I ran rostopic list, this is what I get:

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image
/camera/image/compressed
/camera/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image/compressedDepth
/camera/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image/theora
/camera/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/statistics
/svo/dense_input
/svo/image
/svo/image/compressed
/svo/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/svo/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/svo/image/compressedDepth
/svo/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/svo/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/svo/image/theora
/svo/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/svo/image/theora/parameter_updates
/svo/info
/svo/keyframes
/svo/points
/svo/pose
/svo/remote_key
/tf
```

And when I run rosservice list:

```
/camera/image/compressed/set_parameters
/camera/image/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/camera/image/theora/set_parameters
/image_publisher/get_loggers
/image_publisher/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/rqt_gui_py_node_13721/get_loggers
/rqt_gui_py_node_13721/set_logger_level
/rqt_gui_py_node_13807/get_loggers
/rqt_gui_py_node_13807/set_logger_level
/svo/get_loggers
/svo/image/compressed/set_parameters
/svo/image/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/svo/image/theora/set_parameters
/svo/set_logger_level
```

As you can see, I don't have a /set_camera_info service, which I think is the main problem I am having with trying to run the camera_calibration package. If anyone can please provide me with a simple sample code for using the camera_info_manager, it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: For now, I wish to simply initialize a camera_info_manager object so that I can use its functions to run the set_camera_info service, but I am not well-versed with C++ so I am having some problems understanding the tutorial for camera_info_manager.

EDIT2: I added these two lines in, based on @joq's comments:

```
boost::shared_ptr<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager> cinfo;
cinfo(new camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager(nh));
```

but I only get this error:

```
no match for call to ‘(boost::shared_ptr<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager>) (camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager*)’
cinfo(new camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager(nh));
```

As a separate approach, I have also tried to simply do this to instantiate a camera info manager:

```
camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager cinfo(nh, "camera","");
```

but then I get this error:

```
CMakeFiles/vga_cam_publisher.dir/src/vga_cam_publisher.cpp.o: In function `vga_cam_publisher::vga_cam_publisher()':
vga_cam_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN15vga_cam_publisherC2Ev[_ZN15vga_cam_publisherC5Ev]+0x147): undefined reference to `camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager::CameraInfoManager(ros::NodeHandle, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278602/how-to-use-camera_info_manager-to-publish-camera_info/) by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-01-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2018-01-04**:
Have you tried [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) package. It will automatically start the required service for camera calibration.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-04**:
Yes, I have. But the main problem with the drivers that I looked through was that they did not give me the option to enter a "device_id", just the "device_name". Although I can set the param as "/dev/videoN", I think I need to be able to set the "device_id" to 0 or 1.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-04**:
The error that I would get is `[ERROR] [1515087853.012401358]: VIDIOC_S_FMT error 22, Invalid argument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Camera info manager will declare that service for you. The "tutorial" is just a link to the first driver that used camera_info_manager, not entirely self-explanatory.

To use camera_info_manager, you must:

- include the [camera_info_manager.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.h#L41) header
- declare a [pointer to an instance](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.h#L127)
- allocate an instance of the [CameraInfoManager](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp#L79) class
- set the [camera name](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp#L139)
- [validate and load](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp#L346) previous data from a URL
- [get the current camera_info](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp#L240) when publishing each image frame

There is not a lot more to it than that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-03**:
Thank you, and this might sound like a stupid question but why would we need to declare a pointer to an instance of ImageTransport? And would using Boost really be necessary?

I've also edited my original post to have the error I keep getting when I try to create a CameraInfoManager object

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-03**:
Boost pointers are not required, just useful for avoiding memory leaks. The main advantage of using a pointer is being able to control when the class is instantiated. Sometimes you need to process some ROS parameters first, and a static allocation would happen before then.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-03**:
The error message looks like a CamelCase error in your boost pointer declaration, the class says `camerainfomanager` instead of `CameraInfoManager`.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-03**:
Since you're using C++11, `std::shared_ptr` is built-in, so you don't need Boost.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-03**:
Oh that's weird, the ROS forums text box is changing the case of CameraInfoManager to all lowercase. I do have the error as saying `CameraInfoManager`. I've made it into a code block here to correct it.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-04**:
When I run catkin_make it seems to be able to link my file, but then I get the error about "undefined reference to `camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager::CameraInfoManager(ros::NodeHandle, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, ...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-04**:
Is camera_info_manager listed as a dependency in your package.xml?

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-04**:
It actually isn't but when I added it to the CMakeLists.txt file instead of the package.xml file, the error about undefined reference to CameraInfoManager disappeared. In any case, thank you for all the help. I will now do the rest of the steps you listed on your answer.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-04**:
Now, I'm at the point of setting the camera info url, but I keep getting this error: `no matching function for call to ‘image_transport::CameraPublisher::CameraPublisher(image_transport::Publisher)’ camera_info_url_("")`. What could be causing this error?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-05**:
Re `package.xml`: you *should* list the dependency there, too.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-01-05**:
Maybe you could update your question to show the code you're running now, and where the error appears.